# Case expression syntax error near "as"

Tags: sql, syntax, case

I'm getting an error on my case expression. I just want to evaluate one condition, and return the proper statement. But I keep getting a syntax error near "as".

Here's what I have:

```
left outer join (            
        SELECT wbs1, wbs2, wbs3  
    , case 
            when (ProgramAffiliation = magrann.[programAffiliation_AEP/COHesh2010]()) 
            then '[AEP] as ''AEP1'''
            else [AEP Base] as 'AEP1'
        end
    , [AEP:Non-Compliant Mechanical Ventilation] as 'AEP2'  
    , [AEP - Non Energy Star AC ($90 deduction)] as 'AEP3'  
    , [AEP: Bonus] as 'AEP4'
```

Comment: Missing a closing quote `then '[AEP]' as ''AEP1''` (or an errant open quote)

Comment: The syntax hilighting shows you what's wrong...

Comment: Also, stop using `AS 'foo'` syntax for aliases. Use `AS foo` or, if you need to delimit, use `AS [foo]`. Using single quotes to delimit aliases is deprecated *and* it is confusing (many people see it is a string, which is what it looks like).

Comment: Appreciate the feedback... on both the aliasing and the syntax error.  Couldn't see the forest OR the trees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CASE` Syntax is wrong. You have a column name enclosed in single quotes and you have the alias in two places (both wrong):

```
 , case 
    when (ProgramAffiliation = magrann.[programAffiliation_AEP/COHesh2010]()) 
    then '[AEP] as ''AEP1'''  -- <-- don't put the column in single quotes and no alias here
    else [AEP Base] as 'AEP1'  -- < don't put the alias here
   end  -- < the alias goes here
```

So your `CASE` should be:

```
, case 
    when (ProgramAffiliation = magrann.[programAffiliation_AEP/COHesh2010]()) 
    then [AEP]
    else [AEP Base] 
    end as AEP1
```

The alias goes after the `END` in a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 2):

You should have `end` in `case` before `as`:

```
case 
  when (ProgramAffiliation = magrann.[programAffiliation_AEP/COHesh2010]()) then [AEP] as 
  else [AEP Base] 
end as [AEP1]
// not else [AEP Base]  as 'AEP1' end
```

Updated

Comment: You do realize that your answer is incorrect.  You have single quotes around what appears to be a column name `[AEP]` and the user is actually using the alias in two places.

Comment: @bluefeet : Yeah, thanks... I didn't realize it's possible to make so many mistakes in one line :)